# Java, Regex : Regex to find hashtags slowing down server till it crashes

Tags: java, regex

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which when the user enters comments with #, they are scanned and added as tags. Ideally, there shouldn't be any issue with it normally. But when i deploy the code on server, after each iteration, the server starts to slow down. In 2-3 iterations, the server practically stops and no requests are being served. Removal of that functionality causes everything to work normally. No errors so far. No issues on localhost unfortunately.

Postgresql process log :

```
postgres 27916 22320  0 11:16 ?        00:00:00 postgres: postgres Person2 127.0.0.1(41936) idle                                                                            
postgres 30634 22320  2 13:05 ?        00:00:05 postgres: postgres Person2 127.0.0.1(52105) idle                                                                            
postgres 30718 22320  1 13:05 ?        00:00:03 postgres: postgres Person2 127.0.0.1(52314) idle                                                                            
postgres 30719 22320  1 13:05 ?        00:00:03 postgres: postgres Person2 127.0.0.1(52315) UPDATE waiting                                                                  
postgres 30720 22320  0 13:05 ?        00:00:02 postgres: postgres Person2 127.0.0.1(52316) INSERT waiting                                                                  
postgres 30721 22320  1 13:05 ?        00:00:02 postgres: postgres Person2 127.0.0.1(52317) idle                                                                            
postgres 30722 22320  1 13:05 ?        00:00:02 postgres: postgres Person2 127.0.0.1(52318) UPDATE waiting                                                                  
postgres 30835 22320  0 13:05 ?        00:00:01 postgres: postgres Person2 127.0.0.1(52512) idle in transaction                                                             
postgres 30836 22320  1 13:05 ?        00:00:02 postgres: postgres Person2 127.0.0.1(52520) INSERT waiting
```

Problematic code, main call :

```
  List<String> totalTags = this.groupNotesService.findHashTags(Jsoup.parse(commentText).text());
                if((totalTags!=null)&&(!totalTags.isEmpty())){
                    for(String allTags : totalTags){
                        boolean tagExists = this.groupNotesService.checkIfHashTagAlreadyPartOfTags(allTags,groupNotes.getTags());
                        if(!tagExists){
                            change = true;
                            groupNotes.setTags(groupNotes.getTags()+","+allTags);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(change){
                    this.groupNotesService.directUpdateGroupNote(groupNotes);
                }
```

Code and regex to find hashtags :

```
 @Override
    public List<String> findHashTags(String text){
        if(text == null){
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }

        Set<String> sortedTags = new HashSet<>();
        List<String> processedTags = new ArrayList<>();
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("#\\b.*?\\b#|\\B#\\w+");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        while (matcher.find()){
            String outString = matcher.group();
            outString = outString.replace("#","");
            outString = outString.replace(",","");
            sortedTags.add(outString);
        }
        processedTags.addAll(sortedTags);

        return processedTags;
    }
```

check for existing tags :

```
  @Override
    public boolean checkIfHashTagAlreadyPartOfTags(String tagToCheck, String tags){
        if((tagToCheck==null)||(tagToCheck.isEmpty())){
            return true;
        }
        if(tags == null){
            return false;
        }
        tags = tags.toLowerCase();
        tagToCheck = tagToCheck.toLowerCase();
        String[] tagsSplit = tags.split(",");
        for(String tag : tagsSplit){
             if(tag.equals(tagToCheck)){
                 return true;
             }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

What is going wrong here? Any ideas. Thank you.

Comment: regex `#\\b.*?\\b#|\\B#\\w+` may be improved to `#\\b[^#\n]*\\b#|\\B#\\w+` to limit backtracking

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul : Just tried with deployment on test server, didnt help.

Comment: what are you trying to match with that regex? can you provide some examples?

Comment: @Klaimmore I  have 2 requirements : 1) find words which start with hashtag 2) Find sentences which are enclosed in hashtags. Positive cases are #hello, #how are you#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original regex with the following text:

> some #hashtags #enclosed in sentences#

matches the full sentence `#hashtags #enclosed in sentences#`, but not `#enclosed`

Also, if given a not so long text (over 1000 chars) with plenty of normal #hashtags in the begining of the text, you regex behave poorly:

```
#Lorem #ipsum #dolor #sit #amet, #consectetur #adipiscing #elit, #sed #eiusmod #tempor #incidunt #ut #labore #et #dolore #magna #aliqua. #Ut #enim #ad #minim #veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

As seen here: https://regex101.com/r/pMf9YT/1

23 matches in 35676 steps.

If you modify the regex slightly to `#\b[^#]+\b#|\B#\w+` it matches `#hashtags` and the sentence `#enclosed in sentences#`. And also behave much better: https://regex101.com/r/xHuxpI/2

23 matches in 1767 steps.

Even though this is an improvement, probably it's not the culprit.

Comment: Cool. I will try this out and let you know.

Comment: Looking good, I will confirm it with a tester tomorrow. thanks